# How to mock a generic factory with dependency injection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Using Ninject, I have a factory registered like this:

```
kernel.Bind<IMyFactory>().ToFactory();
```

Where `IMyFactory` looks something like this:

```
public interface IMyFactory
{
    T CreateInstance<T> where T : MyBaseClass;
}
```

The reason for this is that classes derived from `MyBaseClass` have their own dependencies and I needed to be able to create instances of those classes from their types which I do like this:

```
MethodInfo mi = factory.GetType().GetMethod("CreateFoo");
MethodInfo generic = mi.MakeGenericMethod(type);
var param = (MyBaseClass)generic.Invoke(factory, null);
```

Where `factory` is the instance of `IMyFactory` created by Ninject and `type` is the type of `MyBaseClass` derived class I want to create. This all works really well.

The problem is that I'd like to be able to unit test this using the testing framework in Visual Studio and Moq, but I can't figure out a good way to mock `IMyFactory`.

Currently I have this:

```
myFactory = new Mock<IMyFactory>();
myFactory.Setup(d => d.CreateFoo<MyFirstClass>()).Returns(new MyFirstClass(userService.Object));
myFactory.Setup(d => d.CreateFoo<MySecondClass>()).Returns(new MySecondClass(userService.Object, someOtherServiceMock.Object));
// repeat for as many classes as would usually be handled by IMyFactory
```

Obviously this is really tedious (I have a few dozen classes to do). Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What do you actually want to test? The reflection-related creation of the instances or the logic within the classes that implement the interface?

Comment: @khlr: The later. The creation part isn't being tested here. What I'm ultimately testing is whether some methods in `MyBaseClass` are working for every (or at least some) derived classes.

Comment: Well then mocking `IMyFactory` seems not necessary to me. Can't you just normally instantiate the class and invoke its methods to be tested?

Comment: First off, `CreateInstance` has a non-generic overload, so your code is equivalent to `(MyBaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(type)`. Second, does `MyBaseClass` depend on `IMyFactory`? If so, how? You said you're testing functionality in `MyBaseClass` but did not mention how the system under test depend on that factory.

Comment: @dcastro: Ok, `CreateInstance` might be an unfortunate choice of name there. It does not have a non-generic overload and I've edited my question to clear that up (and a couple of other mistakes). The reason why it's set up this way is that a service (lets call it `Finder`) takes an `id` parameter and finds the associated class and creates an instance of it. This was fine when all the derived classes took the same set of parameters (basically an instance of `IUserService`), but later they didn't to have other services injected, hence the factory that lets Ninject take care of it.

Comment: Nevermind what I said about `CreateInstance`, I mistook it for [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx), my bad.

Comment: So, this `Finder` is the one that's using the factory? If so, it seems like the `Finder` is the class you want to test, right?

Comment: @dcastro: So yes, actually I guess I kind of need to test both. But, to test `Finder`, I guess it's sufficient to test to see if it can create any instance of `MyBaseClass` and to test the various sub classes of `MyBaseClass`, I could just test them independent of the `Finder` (as khlr suggested). If `Finder` can create any instance of `MyBaseClass` it *should* be fine unless one of the `MyBaseClass` classes throws an exception during construction - but that can be tested separately by just creating it directly. However, that still leaves a lot of repetitive code to write.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of fiddly, and I'm not sure that it's the right strategy for testing anyway, but here's one approach that seems to work. I created a function in my test class like this:

```
    private Dictionary<Type, Mock> mocks;

    private void SetupCreateFoo<T>(Mock<IMyFactory> myFactory) where T: MyBaseClass 
    {
        var t = typeof(T);
        var constructors = from constructor in t.GetConstructors()
                           let parameters = constructor.GetParameters()
                           where parameters.Length > 0
                           select new { constructor, parameters };

        // Note: there should only be one constructor anyway           
        foreach (var c in constructors)
        {
            List<object> parameters = new List<object>();
            foreach (var p in c.parameters)
            {
                parameters.Add(mocks[p.ParameterType].Object);
            }
            myFactory.Setup(d => d.CreateAnalytic<T>()).Returns((T)c.constructor.Invoke(parameters.ToArray()));
        }
    }
```

Where the dictionary `mocks` is a collection of mocked services that might be needed by classes derived from `MyBaseClass`.

Now where I setup my test class, I can do this:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        userService = new Mock<IUserService>();
        //... setup userService
        someOtherServiceMock = new Mock<ISomeOtherService>();
        //... setup someOtherService

        mocks = new Dictionary<Type, Mock>()
        {
            { typeof(IUserService), userService },
            { typeof(ISomeOtherService), someOtherServiceMock}
        };

        myFactory= new Mock<IMyFactory>();
        SetupCreateFoo<MyFirstClass>(myFactory);
        SetupCreateFoo<MySecondClass>(myFactory);
        // ... etc
        finderService = new FinderService(userService.Object, myFactory.Object);

    }
```

And I *think* I could potentially set up a `List<Type>` and call `SetupCreateFoo<T>` in a loop to further reduce the repetition, but it would require some reflection again to call a generic method with the `Type`.

Answer (score 0):

It's still unclear to me why you need to mock `IMyFactory`, but to answer your core question: no, Moq offers now way to setup a generic method for any generic type parameter. I contribute to an open source project which integrates with Moq and I've faced this limitation before.

But you should only be setting up the method for the generic type parameters that are relevant to the test. If your test needs the factory to be setup with a hand full of type parameters, then that sounds like either a code smell or an exotic edge case.